# django orm categorize by some field

Tags: django

```
class Example(models.Model):
    types = models.CharField(choices=Choice('A', 'B', 'C',  max_length=4)
```

and I want to get a result like this

```
{ 
    'A' : [ExampleObject(1), ExampleObject(3), ExampleObject(4)],
    'B' : [ExampleObject(2), ExampleObject(6)],
    'C' : [ExampleObject(5), ExampleObject(7), ExampleObject(8)]
}
```

Are there any neat orm functions without using too many functions?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to define your type choices as a ForeignKey. type is a python reserved word. I'm not sure I understand your models, but I would guess you have both classes of Model and ModelObject (feel a bit queasy about using Model because django uses models.Model). I would suggest:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    category_letter = models.CharField(max_length=1)


class Example(models.Model):
     category = models.ForeignKey(Category)    
     instance_info = [whatever info]

answer = {}
for category in Category.objects.all():
    answer[category.category_letter] = category.example_set.values_list('instance_info', flat=True)
```

answer should be what you want. "example_set" is a shortcut Django makes for every model.  In Django, as in Python, class names use Capitals, instance names use lowercase.

Comment: Oops! I was stupid. I changed the class name to Example. Would this also change your answer?  The answer you wrote above is based on the original version I guess.

Comment: No the names don't really change my answer (which is that I think you will need to get the instance list for the category via a loop. They just make your problem a bit clearer though, I still think "ExampleObject(1)" looks like instance number 1 of a model called ExampleObject (in Django that would be initialising a new ExampleObject with a value of 1).